# Errors in the solution of large linear systems with the QR factorization

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

The QR decomposition can be used to solve linear systems of the form Ax=b, say of order n, but it induces a considerable increasing relative (or absolute) errors on the unknowns x, specifically the ones with the highest orders when the system dimension is large.

Any explanation for this fact?

Thank you.

Comment: Which algorithm do you consider? Simple Gram-Schmidt? Householder reflections? Givens rotations?

Comment: Householder reflections.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what your "error" means and make more clear what kind of systems you want to solve (e.g., if the "instability" is related to the problem)?

Comment: I mean the relative (or absolute) errors related to the unknowns x (vector of dimension n) in a linear system Ax=b. The instability is related to the algorithm and not the problem.

Comment: QR factorization is known for being a very stable method for solving $Ax=b$.

Comment: Householder reflections provide one of the most stable implementations of the QR factorization (if implemented properly). You need to include more details if you expect the question to be answered. For example, you may provide more details on your "instability" observations, for what systems, quantify the errors, etc..

Comment: When using Householder reflectors to implement QR factorization, the "things are worse for the higher index term" comment does not really make any sense. By contrast that makes perfect sense if you use Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 1):

The QR method of solving linear equations is normwise backward stable, but not componentwise backward stable. The LU method of solving linear equations is normwise backward stable and componentwise backward stable.

Therefore if $A$ has large standard condition number but small Skeel condition number, then the forward error of solving the problem $Ax = b$ using the QR method can be much larger, than the forward error using the LU method.